# Multiple request in the same file NextJs

Tags: next.js

I am learning Next Js and I was creating my endpoints in login and user registration, and I have a question regarding the routes for the APIS in Next Js.

How can I apply multiple requests in the same file, for example I have this code:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    if (req.url === "/api/auth/login") {
      handleLogin(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/api/auth/register") {
      handleRegister(req, res);
    }
  }
}

const handleLogin = (req, res) => {
  const { userName, password } = req.body;
  res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: { userName, password } });
};

const handleRegister = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: "register" });
};
```

and how i used it is like this:

http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login

the problem is that I have 404 error, when I remove the conditions it works but i have to select one of the functions.